# Do I need to implement my own destructors for my derived classes if they don't contain static data?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, destructor, virtual-destructor

Let's say I have:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
}

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    ~Derived();
}
```

In my code I need to delete `Derived` classes through a `Base` pointer, like this:

```
delete[] pt_base;
```

However, I don't actually have anything to destroy in the implemented destructors. But I still need them to delete through the base class?

What's the best way to achieve what I want without a whole lot of wasted code and empty destructors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, virtual destructor declaration/definition of the `Base` class is sufficient, though making it abstract requires you give this destructor in the `Derived` class.

If you just declare

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {} // <<< Have a definition
};
```

you don't need to specify any destructors in inherited classes.

Comment: "Virtual constructor"??

Comment: Np. BTW do you like my standard citations?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's all citations from [tag:c++11]. Though you're certainly right for the current standard (and I appreciate keeping up with that), what I posted in my answer used to work for me in the last decades? Is it invalid now?

Comment: Huh? What's wrong with C++11? I can post the equivalent wording from C++03 and C++14 if you'd like.

Comment: This "solution" entirely changes the program by making `Base` no longer an interface. Not sure why it's so highly voted.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Did I say anything is wrong with it? Just the opposite, didn't I?

Comment: I honestly don't know _what_ you're saying about it! You pointed out that I quoted C++11: did you mean to say that this was a good or a bad thing?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm referring to that `= default;` syntax, that's available with at least c++11 IIRC.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit /OT BTW your least avatar was a much better choice ;-) ...

Comment: Okay then yes that has only been in the language since C++11 that is true. [GCC has had it since 4.4 (2012)](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html); [Visual Studio since VS2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As mentioned, no disagreement from my side (upvoted your answer).

Comment: Yes, considering [that is invalid syntax and will prevent the program from being compiled](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/920d0abb250bda28), I think you're right to say it would do little more than to confuse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65920/discussion-between---and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide a destructor with a "default" implementation, then the `default` keyword is provided for precisely this purpose. It results in a user-declared destructor that has the same behaviours as an implicitly-defined one.

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    ~Derived() = default;
}
```

This is equivalent to providing an empty destructor body like `{}`, but may better display your intent.

**But, no, you don't *need* to provide these destructors:**

> `[C++11: 12.4/4]:` **If a class has no user-declared destructor, a destructor is implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4).** An implicitly-declared destructor is an `inline public` member of its class.
>
> `[C++11: 12.4/5]:` A defaulted destructor for a class `X` is defined as deleted if:
>
> - `X` is a union-like class that has a variant member with a non-trivial destructor,
> - any of the non-static data members has class type `M` (or array thereof) and M has a deleted destructor or a destructor that is inaccessible from the defaulted destructor,
> - any direct or virtual base class has a deleted destructor or a destructor that is inaccessible from the defaulted destructor,
> - or, for a virtual destructor, lookup of the non-array deallocation function results in an ambiguity or in a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted destructor.
>
> *[..]*

None of these rules apply here, and no rule exists to change this behaviour in the case that a base class has a pure or impure virtual destructor, so the implicitly-declared destructor in my example above is not deleted (i.e. valid).

The following wording is another strong clue that the derived destructor can be declared for you:

> `[C++11: 12.4/9]:` A destructor can be declared `virtual` (10.3) or pure `virtual` (10.4); if any objects of that class or any derived class are created in the program, the destructor shall be defined. **If a class has a base class with a virtual destructor, its destructor (whether user- or implicitly-declared) is `virtual`.**

---

Unfortunately you won't be able to use `default` for the Base class if you want the destructor to be pure; you'll still have to provide its [empty] definition separately:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
};

Base::~Base() {}
```